# Logging into a MongoDB collection (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, logging, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with a Ruby (sinatra) applicaion.  Currently, all logging is done to local files.  I would instead like to place log messages into a MongoDB collection. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source project that does just that:

https://github.com/customink/central_logger

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that this is a Rails gem, and as I said in my question, I'm not using Rails.  Have you used this in a non-rails environment? If so how much hacking is involved to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Load data from files.
2. Insert logs into mongodb collection([here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html) detailed ruby driver tutolrial).
3. In method that log data instead of writing in the file just insert logs in mongodb collection.

Also [capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collectionshttp://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) good fit for such tasks as logging.

Comment: Exactly. I need to know how do I do step 3 without rewriting all the logging lines?

Answer (score 1):

When you use MongoDB for logging, the concern is high write throughput. Although MongoDB's insert is fire-and-forget style by default, calling a lot of insert() causes a heavy write lock contention. This could affect the application performance, and prevent the readers to aggregate / filter the stored logs.

One solution might be using the log collector framework such as [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/), [Logstash](http://logstash.net/), or [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/). These daemons are supposed to be launched at every application nodes, and takes the logs from app processes.

[image: Fluentd plus MongoDB]

They buffer the logs and asynchronously writes out the data to other systems like MongoDB / PostgreSQL / etc. The write is done by batches, so it's a lot more efficient than writing directly from apps. This link describes how to put the logs into Fluentd from Ruby program.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Ruby Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/ruby)
- [Fluentd + MongoDB: The Easiest Way to Log Your Data Effectively](http://blog.10gen.com/post/27619817959/fluentd-mongodb-the-easiest-way-to-log-your-data) on 10gen blog